# Foreach array organization/iteration

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach, iteration

I have this array that I've tried iterating over and creating a new array:

```
array(233) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["subject_id"]=>
    int(138)
    ["relatedsubject_id"]=>
    int(127)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["subject_id"]=>
    int(138)
    ["relatedsubject_id"]=>
    int(47)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["subject_id"]=>
    int(138)
    ["relatedsubject_id"]=>
    int(13)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["subject_id"]=>
    int(138)
    ["relatedsubject_id"]=>
    int(56)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["subject_id"]=>
    int(154)
    ["relatedsubject_id"]=>
    int(77)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["subject_id"]=>
    int(154)
    ["relatedsubject_id"]=>
    int(69)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["subject_id"]=>
    int(154)
    ["relatedsubject_id"]=>
    int(70)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["subject_id"]=>
    int(154)
    ["relatedsubject_id"]=>
    int(75)
```

I cut it short so it's not too obnoxious.  This is the code I'm using now:

```
    $subject_id = array();
    foreach ($results as $mainKey => $subArrays) {
        if(!isset($subject_id[$results[$mainKey]["subject_id"]])) {
            $subject_id[$results[$mainKey]["subject_id"]] = array();
            array_push($subject_id[$results[$mainKey]["subject_id"]], $results[$mainKey]["relatedsubject_id"]);
            // $subject_id[$results[$mainKey]["subject_id"]][] = $results[$mainKey]["relatedsubject_id"];
        }
    }

var_dump($subject_id);
```

My results look like this:

```
array(111) {
  [138]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(127)
  }
  [154]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(77)
  }
```

Any ideas on why I'm only getting 1 value and how to modify to get each "relatedsubject_id" to fall in line with the corresponding "subject_id"?  Thank you.

*Edit*

Expected Result:

```
array {
      [138]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        int(127)
        [1]=>
        int(47)
        [2]=>
        int(13)
        [3]=>
        int(56)
      }
      [154]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        int(77)
        [1]=>
        int(69)
        [2]=>
        int(70)
        [3]=>
        int(75)
      }
```

Comment: Can you post how you want your array to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to consolidate your subject ids and relatedsubject_ids.  If thats the case, this may work for you.

```
    $subject_id = array();
    foreach ($results as $mainKey => $subArrays) {
      if(!isset($subject_id[$results[$mainKey]['subject_id']])) {
        $subject_id[$results[$mainKey]['subject_id']] = array('subject_id' => $results[$mainKey]['subject_id'], 'relatedsubject_id' => array());
      }
      $subject_id[$results[$mainKey]['subject_id']]['relatedsubject_id'][] = $results[$mainKey]["relatedsubject_id"];
    }
```

Changed to your EDIT

```
$subject_id = array();
foreach ($results as $mainKey => $subArrays) {
  if(!isset($subject_id[$results[$mainKey]['subject_id']])) {
    $subject_id[$results[$mainKey]['subject_id']] = array();
  } 
  $subject_id[$results[$mainKey]['subject_id']][] = $results[$mainKey]["relatedsubject_id"];
}
```

The reason why you were only getting one result is you had all your code in the if(!isset()) function.  That should only not be set once.  If that makes sense.